# as3 acces child from super/base class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im building a flash app where i have created views that extends a base view class. I can't get my head around hoe to remove the view from stage tho. I want to call something like: super.kill(); which should remove the child.

Im adding my child view to stage in main.as by running this.

```
    var _idleView: IdleView = new IdleView();
    addChild(_idleView);
```

My idleView.as constructor looks like this:

```
    public class IdleView extends BaseView {

    public function IdleView():void {


        super();
    }
}
```

And my baseView.as looks like this:

```
    public class BaseView extends Sprite {

    public function BaseView():void {
        this.alpha = 0;
        init();
    }

    protected function init():void {
        TweenLite.to(this, 1, {alpha:1}); 
    }

    protected function kill():void {

    }
}
```

So i basically wonder how i can run kill() in base view by calling it from the child view? And it should run removeChild so the added child gets removed itself.

Comment: I don't think a child can remove itself from the displaylist of its parent. Why not simply use `removeChild(_idleView)` in the Object that added it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, to remove view from parent use this:

```
if (this.parent)
   this.parent.removeChild(this);
```

You can access kill() method from child class without any troubles, cause it's protected.

Comment: Thanks! so basically i can run super.kill() from the child and then put your code in the kill()?

Comment: Just kill(). You should use super.kill() if you override basic kill method in child, but want to call basic implementation.

Comment: this does the job but is a wrong solution since it creates a dependency. Better would be for any child to dispatch an event showing its intent to be removed. The parent can then listen (or not -> no dependency) to that event and properly remove the child that requested it. Having child telling parent what to do creates dependencies that makes code very rigid, instead have child request parent of something and let parent decide what to do.

Comment: BotMaster, on the other hand dispatch an event its VERY slow way, cause it provides alloc a new instance of event and so on. If your project have hundred of elements (e.g. some scrollable grid with good amount of content) you will see lack of performance. But in most cases your parent object or any other controller knows when to remove childs without any dispatches and accesses from childs :)